# Getting result from extraction rule in Coded Web Test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, automated-tests

I've been trying to extract the result from an extraction rule in a coded Web Test (VS2008). I want to extract the URL from an  tag in testA and feed it into testB's run parameters. I've been stepping thru testA's code until just after the "yield return WebTestRequest" statement.
Is this possible?

Snippet of code:

```
ExtractAttributeValue();
            extractionRule6.TagName = "a";
            extractionRule6.AttributeName = "href";
            extractionRule6.MatchAttributeName = "";
            extractionRule6.MatchAttributeValue = "";
            extractionRule6.HtmlDecode = true;
            extractionRule6.Required = true;
            extractionRule6.Index = 0;
            extractionRule6.ContextParameterName = "";
            extractionRule6.ContextParameterName = "fifth";
            request2.ExtractValues += new EventHandler<ExtractionEventArgs>(extractionRule6.Extract);
                  yield return request2;
```

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. By accessing the Context object straight after returning the WebTestRequest. I used the TryGetValue method of Context. Code added below. My extraction rule is named "firstprj". I was also able to skip all remaining WebTestRequests using the bool this method returns if there is no URL found.

```
        WebTestRequest request2 = new WebTestRequest("http://tramdev/MyProjects.aspx");
        request2.Method = "POST";
        request2.Headers.Add(new WebTestRequestHeader("x-microsoftajax", "Delta=true"));
        FormPostHttpBody request2Body = new FormPostHttpBody();
        request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("ctl00$cphMain$SM", "ctl00$cphMain$pnlLoadCurtain|ctl00$cphMain$btnSearch");
        request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("__EVENTTARGET", this.Context["$HIDDEN1.__EVENTTARGET"].ToString());
        request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("__EVENTARGUMENT", this.Context["$HIDDEN1.__EVENTARGUMENT"].ToString());
        request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("__LASTFOCUS", this.Context["$HIDDEN1.__LASTFOCUS"].ToString());
        request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("__VIEWSTATE", this.Context["$HIDDEN1.__VIEWSTATE"].ToString());
        request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("__EVENTVALIDATION", this.Context["$HIDDEN1.__EVENTVALIDATION"].ToString());
        request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("ctl00$cphMain$txtProjectName", "");
        request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("ctl00$cphMain$txtOpenStartDate", "");
        request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("ctl00$cphMain$txtOpenEndDate", "");
        request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("ctl00$cphMain$ddlAOR", "--All--");
        request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("ctl00$cphMain$ddlSubAOR", "--All--");
        request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("ctl00$cphMain$ddlContact", "0");
        request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("ctl00$cphMain$lstProjectStatus", "Applied for Charter");
        request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("ctl00$cphMain$gvPrjSearch$ctl02$txtstatus", "");
        request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("ctl00$cphMain$gvPrjSearch$ctl03$txtstatus", "");
        request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("ctl00$cphMain$gvPrjSearch$ctl06$txtstatus", "");
        request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("__ASYNCPOST", "true");
        request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("ctl00$cphMain$btnSearch", "Search");
        request2.Body = request2Body;
        ExtractAttributeValue extractionRule2 = new ExtractAttributeValue();
        extractionRule2.TagName = "a";
        extractionRule2.AttributeName = "href";
        extractionRule2.MatchAttributeName = "";
        extractionRule2.MatchAttributeValue = "";
        extractionRule2.HtmlDecode = true;
        extractionRule2.Required = true;
        extractionRule2.Index = 5;
        extractionRule2.ContextParameterName = "";
        extractionRule2.ContextParameterName = "firstprj";
        request2.ExtractValues += new EventHandler<ExtractionEventArgs>(extractionRule2.Extract);
        yield return request2;
        request2 = null;

        // get prjId of first record in project list (href in extracted attribute value)
        bool urlFound;
        object firstProjectUrlObj;
        string prjId;

        urlFound = Context.TryGetValue("firstprj", out firstProjectUrlObj);
```